# Webpage hosted HTML editor that graphically shows tag nesting in WYSIWYG view

Tags: html-editor

I once found a webpage hosted HTML editor that optionally included the tags, as highlighted colour coded elements with the tag type, in the (almost) WYSIWYG view, but now cannot find the project anywhere.

I thought it an excellent compromise between WYSIWYG ease of use an markup flexibility.

Does anyone know which editor this was?  Or maybe there is more then one editor with this feature?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is one that looks promising.

http://koivi.com/WYSIWYG-Editor/

This appears to match your request.

Answer (score 0):

I found one such, and only one.  Unfortunately it isn't the one I had seen before and so I'm still looking.  They are called What You See Is What You Mean editors - WYSIWYM.

[WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/)

[image: Screenshot]

Also see - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM